# How do i send a message to a specific channel by the bot no matter command is issued in any channel

Tags: javascript, discord.js

If I know the channel ID, say "123453533908334" and I want the discord bot to send a message to that channel only no matter which channel the command is issued. I am working on discord.js. Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

```js
client.guilds.cache.get("your_guild_id").channels.cache.get("123453533908334").send("your_text")
```

Comment: You should add more details about why this works. For example, say what `client.guilds.cache.get` does.